# input type="text" with no echo?

Tags: javascript, html, echo

New to JS.
I'd like to be able to set up a text box that does not show anything the user types into it, but instead shows a character at a time of a message I hid in the code.
I have it ALMOST working, but it appears the HTML input gets plotted to the text box after the JS writes it's output to the box leaving a single annoying letter behind.
Since this seems to happen after executing the function, just clearing the box from JS does not seem to help.  Greatly appreciate your help.  I'm new to JS so your explanation can't be too simple for me!  Thanks.  Here's my almost working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p>In one sentence below, descibe free will.</p>
    <input type="text" id="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
    <script>
        var i = 0;
        var will = "There is no free will.";

        function myFunction() {
            i = i + 1;
            document.getElementById("text").value = will.substring(0, i) + "  ";  

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem lies in the timing of the `keydown` event. At the time it is fired, the value of the `input` is not changed yet, use `keyup` event instead, or rather `input` event, it takes care of the dropped, pasted and cutted values too.

Comment: Spectacular!  I spent 2 hours before I asked, and your reply fixed it in 5 seconds.  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: The onkeydown event does not get fired if the user right-clicks and pastes text into the field. A more thorough solution would be to use the oninput (IE9+), onchange (IE9+) and/or onpropertychange (<=IE8) events

Comment: @user3163495 `onpropertychange` is a bit dangerous event, it fires also when the changes are made programmatically. In OP's case it would lead to infinite series of that event firing. `onchange` will fire only after the target losts the focus ...

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of difference in approaches, but you can use `keyup`:

```html
<p>In one sentence below, descibe free will.</p>
<input type="text" id="text" onkeyup="myFunction(event)">
<script>
  var i = 0;
  var will = "There is no free will.";

  function myFunction(e) {
    i = i + 1;
    document.getElementById("text").value = will.substring(0, i) + "  ";
  }
</script>
```

or `input`:

```html
<p>In one sentence below, descibe free will.</p>
<input type="text" id="text" oninput="myFunction(event)">
<script>
  var i = 0;
  var will = "There is no free will.";

  function myFunction(e) {
    i = i + 1;
    document.getElementById("text").value = will.substring(0, i) + "  ";
  }
</script>
```

or `keydown` + `event.preventDefault()`:

```html
<p>In one sentence below, descibe free will.</p>
<input type="text" id="text" onkeydown="myFunction(event)">
<script>
  var i = 0;
  var will = "There is no free will.";

  function myFunction(e) {
    i = i + 1;
    document.getElementById("text").value = will.substring(0, i) + "  ";
    e.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The onkeydown event does not get fired if the user right-clicks and pastes text into the field. A more thorough solution would be to use the oninput (IE9+), onchange (IE9+) and/or onpropertychange (<=IE8) events

Comment: Have a look at both demos, they differ a little in the final effect. Try them out.

Comment: Also OP, make sure you understand that backspace is also an `onkeydown` event. You might be better off using a hidden input and simply using substring on your `will` variable using the length of your hidden input value.

Comment: Yes, so does the pasting or moving count as `input`.

Comment: @acdcjunior Not disagreeing with your answer - simply providing information for OP as I can imagine they haven't considered how many different actions include button presses yet don't change text in a way OP might think (it doesn't add a character like pressing `a` or `b` (backspace, CTRL sequences, enter, arrow keys etc. etc.)).

Comment: Yes, sure thing. I too thank you for that. Learning a lot from this.